# How to program a MySQL trigger to insert rows into another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables, one is a `users` table and another is a `connectedto` table. The users table loks like so:

```
USERS_TABLE:

ID | username
1  | usera
2  | userb
```

The connectedto table looks like so:

```
CONNECTED_TABLE: 

con_id | con_from | con_to 
1      | 1        | 2 
2      | 2        |1
```

I want to place a trigger on `USERS` table such that upon adding of a user in the users table, the `connectedto` table changes such that the new user is connected to each and every other previous user AND each and every other previous user is connected to the new user. Kindly help.

Comment: If every user is connected to every other user, why store it in a database as it is true for all cases?

Comment: I just put a section of the db that is important for my solution to work. There is other business logic that requires the db to work like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I see no sense in that, to be honest.

You can easily create your connected_table on the fly like in this example:

```
create table foo(id int);
insert into foo values (1), (2);

select f1.id, f2.id from foo f1, foo f2
where f1.id != f2.id;
```

Result:

```
1   2
2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this simple trigger example:

ex:

Two tables like table1 , table2:

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRI_table1
AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO table2 (contact_id, count) VALUES
(new.contact_id,0)
```

i hope it's use full for you.